# Pullback bundle of bundle from real projective space to complex projective space

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Let $V$ be complex vector space. As we know there is canonical map $\mathbb P(V_\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb P(V)$. Furthermore, let $H(V)=\{(\ell,v) : v \in\ell\}$ and we have a bundle $H(V)\rightarrow\mathbb P(V)$.

How can I see that realification pullback of these two bundles  is isomorphic to $H(V_\mathbb{R})\oplus H(V_\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: So your canonical map sends $\ell_{\Bbb R} \rightsquigarrow \ell_{\Bbb R}\oplus i\ell_{\Bbb R}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes exactly.

Answer (score 1):

As a real vector bundle the pullback has fiber over $x \in P(V_\mathbb{R})$ equal to $F_x \oplus i F_x$ where $F_x$ is the tautological fiber over $x$. Clearly, $iF_x$ is isomorphic to $F_x$ as real vector bundles, so we have the result.

Comment: How can I see that F_x is tautological fiber? You mean tautological line bundle when you say tautological fiber?

Comment: You say as much in your comment. If you believe your comment, then you are done.